# How to handle answers that commit copyright infringement?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I posted a canned comment on [this link only answer](https://serverfault.com/a/966001/38644), stating that

> [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

The author of the answer reacted by copying & pasting a large section of that knowledge base article into the answer, which, while it certainly improves the answer a great deal, violates VMwares copyright on that article.

Is this a legal problem for SF? or just for the author of the answer? How should such answers be handled?

Comment: Note that the answer has been edited and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The text says to *include the **essential** parts of the answer*. If the author of the answer does that and only that, it would fall under the fair use doctrine - see [the U.S. Copyright Office's information on Fair Use](https://www.copyright.gov/fair-use/more-info.html). But if the author, as you say, copies and pastes a large portion of copyrighted text, presenting it as their own, that would be both legally and morally wrong.

When you discover plagiarism or copyright violation, you should flag it to the moderators and let them decide how to take actions. See e.g. ["Possible plagiarism detected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384566/1379627) and ["Post deleted due to DMCA notice"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382778/1379627) on meta.SO.

Comment: ah, `plagiarism` was not a term I was search for before asking the question. I was searching for `copyright` and `infringement` and couldn't find anything. I guess we can close this as a duplicate to your linked question then, so others can find it more easily in the future

Comment: Well, the questions/answers I linked are on meta.SO, not meta.SF, so I don't know if we can close it as duplicate.

Comment: I looked over there since it seemed to me that it's a network-wide question rather than a site question.

Comment: Closing as duplicate only works within a site, for some reason.

Comment: /me considers copying and pasting the answer from the dupe. :-p

Comment: @tudor all the answers here on the site are licensed to StackOverflow in perpetuity, so that would probably actually be legally OK :-) (though it would generally be considered polite to include an attribution to the original author)